# How do I set reminders using Voice Actions in ICS 4 - Galaxy Nexus?

Tags: notifications, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, voice-command

Willing to pay for an app.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [My Voice Reminder](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.apperhand.my.reminder.widget.pro&hl=en). Its a free app. Don't know if it supports ICS.

Comment: Looks like this just allows you to record voice with a reminder, not set one just with your voice